# Monomial order in Macaulay2

Tags: macaulay2

When I define the ring to work on in Macaulay2, I would like to change the order of the variables for building the Grobner basis of ideals with respect to this new order. For instance, if set
`R = QQ [x_1..x_5]`, then how may I define the lexicographic monomial order induced by `x_3<x_2<x_1<x_5<x_4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ordering of the variables is whatever order you use to write them when creating the ring.

For instance, to get the order you want, you should use

```
R = QQ[x_3, x_2, x_1, x_5, x_4]
```

Indeed, on my version of Macaualy2 we can see the desired behavior:

```
i1 : R = QQ[x_3, x_2, x_1, x_5, x_4]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : x_1 + x_2 + x_4

o2 = x  + x  + x
      2    1    4

o2 : R
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this automatically, though, and a quick look through [the documentation](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.18/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_monomial_sporderings.html) makes it look like there might not be a way to do that.

---

I hope this helps ^_^